# How do CPython and PyPy decide when to resize a set?

Tags: python, set, cpython, pypy, python-internals

When adding elements to sets on CPython and PyPy, when are they resized, and what will be the sizes of the underlying container?

This question is similar in principle to `max_load_factor`, [as C++ describes it for their `unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/max_load_factor/).

Comment: This is just something I recently looked at and I thought I'd do a quick write up, which served as a good way to double-check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython uses [this check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L351) to decide when to resize:

```
if (!(so->used > n_used && so->fill*3 >= (so->mask+1)*2))
```

This basically means that when 2/3 full, the container will resize.

The resizing itself doubles the amount of space for large sets and quadruples it for small ones:

```
return set_table_resize(so, so->used>50000 ? so->used*2 : so->used*4);
```

Armin Rigo points out in the comments that PyPy implements its sets with dictionaries, so the [relevant resizing code](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/raw/default/rpython/rtyper/lltypesystem/rdict.py) is:

```
jit.conditional_call(d.resize_counter <= x * 3,
                     _ll_dict_resize_to, d, num_extra)
```

This is the same strategy, as `resize_counter` is the empty space left in the dictionary.

---

Before this was pointed this out, I resorted to benchmarking. You can detect resizes by looking for very small pauses. This is somewhat random for small sizes, so you have to be careful to remove the noise. Here's a script that does that:

```
from collections import Counter
import time

iterations = 100
internal_iterations = 100000

def main():
    resizes = Counter()

    for i in range(iterations):
        print("Completion: [{:3.0%}]\r".format(i/iterations), end="")

        s = set()
        maxtime_so_far = 0
        for j in range(internal_iterations):
            start = time.time()
            s.add(j)
            end = time.time()

            if end-start > maxtime_so_far:
                maxtime_so_far = end-start
                resizes[j] += 1

    print()

    format_string = "{0:<6} = 0b{0:<18b} [found %: {1:2.0%}]"

    for index in sorted(resizes):
        chance = resizes[index] / iterations

        if chance >= 0.05:
            print(format_string.format(index, chance))

main()
```

and here's the output for CPython:

```
Completion: [99%]
0      = 0b0                  [found %: 100%]
5      = 0b101                [found %: 83%]
21     = 0b10101              [found %: 12%]
85     = 0b1010101            [found %: 94%]
341    = 0b101010101          [found %: 97%]
1365   = 0b10101010101        [found %: 100%]
5461   = 0b1010101010101      [found %: 100%]
21845  = 0b101010101010101    [found %: 100%]
87381  = 0b10101010101010101  [found %: 100%]
```

You can see the `10101...₂` pattern, which is what you get from a power of two divided by three, which is when the object will resize. (It's resizes one after that, because the script is 0-indexed).

On PyPy3, changing the number of iterations to be greater (`iterations = 1000; internal_iterations = 100000`), I get

```
Completion: [100%]
0      = 0b0                  [found %: 78%]
5      = 0b101                [found %: 6%]
21     = 0b10101              [found %: 5%]
341    = 0b101010101          [found %: 24%]
1365   = 0b10101010101        [found %: 66%]
5461   = 0b1010101010101      [found %: 100%]
21845  = 0b101010101010101    [found %: 100%]
87381  = 0b10101010101010101  [found %: 71%]
```

This implies the strategy is the same for PyPy.

Strangely, and possibly due to the JIT or GC, sometimes I get something more like:

```
Completion: [100%]
0      = 0b0                  [found %: 13%]
5      = 0b101                [found %: 11%]
21     = 0b10101              [found %: 22%]
22     = 0b10110              [found %: 6%]
23     = 0b10111              [found %: 5%]
24     = 0b11000              [found %: 5%]
341    = 0b101010101          [found %: 30%]
1365   = 0b10101010101        [found %: 66%]
5461   = 0b1010101010101      [found %: 98%]
```

depending on iteration counts. I imagine this is due to the relatively small number of iterations around that point, and it probably doesn't mean very much. If a GC collection happens around item 20, it's liable to cause that sort of stress.

Comment: Resizing the set has never been in `setobject.py`.  Instead, it's in the [RPython implementation of dictionaries](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/raw/default/rpython/rtyper/lltypesystem/rdict.py).  Sets are just dictionaries with "void" values for RPython.